# Refer to the matched string in regex in sed?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am trying to do the following:

I have a file which contains html tags like `"<span class='A'> blah </span>"`, `"<span class='B'> blah </span>"` etc.

and I want to replace all occurences of `"<span class='A'> blah </span>"` by `** blah **`. So I tried using sed.

`sed "s/<span class='A'>/*/g" myfile` followed by,

`sed "s/<\span>/*/g" myfile`

This nearly gets me what I want but also messes up the end span tags for other classes, which I do not want.

Ideally, I would want some way to refer the text matched by [^<]* in

`sed s/<span class='A'>[^<]*</span>/my_replacement_character/g`.

Comment: Wrap it in parenthesis and access the captured group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a capturing group and a backreference.  In most regex flavors you can specify a capturing group with parentheses, in sed you need to escape the parentheses, so you would change `[^<]*` to `\([^<]*\)`.  Then in your replacement you can use `\1` to refer to whatever was captured.

In the end, it should look something like this:

```
sed "s/<span class='A'>\([^<]*\)<\/span>/**\1**/g"
```

In some GNU sed (and possibly other implementations) you can use the `-r` or `--regexp-extended` flag to make sed regex more consistent with other flavors.  That way you wouldn't need to escape the parentheses:

```
sed -r "s/<span class='A'>([^<]*)<\/span>/**\1**/g"
```

Comment: Found it myself a few seconds ago. Still will accept this as the correct answer.
Thanks!